# Kotlin function to count win rate after given instruction

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function SendInstruction which send instructions to the user to press a button with label x for 3 seconds. I have four buttons with labels y,z and w.

```
fun SendInstruction(buttonLabel:String):String{
return buttonLabel
}
```

I have a counter that either increments by 20 if correct sent instruction matches user clicked button and decrements if not correct.

But when correct for 3 seconds then another instruction can be sent for button y otherwise user must pass button x to go to y and also must pass y to go to z and must pass z to go to w

Here is what i tried so far

```
var counter:Int = 0

GlobalScope.launch{
SendInstruction("click button x")
if(userclicked)//always true for 3 seconds
   delay(3000)//check in 3s if instructions matches user clicked
   counter +=20
   SendInstruction("click button y")
   if(userclicked)//always true for 3 s
      delay(3000)//check in 3s if instruction matches user clicked
else
   counter = 0
   //restart
}
```

But it just doesn't work, can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: How r you matching the instructions ? that code is missing .. You must be setting some variable when u click any button and matching it later . I think thats the logic u r missing .

Comment: That is what i don't know how do or how to implement

Comment: This is complete custom logic . What if user Press all the Buttons for first time in 3 second Window X->Y->Z->W ., what will happen then ?

Comment: Thats a problem too,

Comment: Now i get you maybe i should check the counter variable to see its value which will make me proceed to send instruction or not, that is for button x 20, y 40 z 60 and w 80

Comment: I would Suggest you better write a pseudo Code first which is covering all the edge case then only start writing the actual code . If you face problem in writing code add the pseudo Code with question then only anyone here can help you not without it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a timeout pattern, like a reverse debounce catch, to help here. Here is an example, where you set a click target and a coroutine that will reset the target in 3 seconds. If you click the target in that time the coroutine is cancelled and you move to the next target.

```kotlin
private var job: Job? = null
private var target = ""
private var score = 0

fun onClick(btn: String, next: String) {
    if(btn == target) {
        advance(next)
    }
    else {
        // Handle wrong click by starting over
        reset()
    }
}

fun advance(next: String) {
    // Handle a correct click by cancelling
    // the coroutine, updating the score,
    // and setting the next target

    // Cancel the timeout
    job?.cancel()

    // Add to the score
    score += 20

    // Set the next/end case
    if(next.isEmpty()) {
        SendInstruction("you won")
    }
    else {
        updateTarget(next)
    }
}

fun updateTarget(next: String) {
    // Update the target, notify the user,
    // and start a coroutine to reset
    // the target in 3 seconds

    target = next

    SendInstruction("Click on $next")

    // Reset the target after 3 seconds
    // unless the coroutine is cancelled
    // by a correct button click first
    job = lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(3000)
        reset()
    }
}

fun reset() {
    // Start over on a wrong click
    // or a timeout. Alternately could
    // just show "game over" and make
    // them click "Go" or something to start over
    job?.cancel()
    target = ""
    score = 0
    updateTarget("x")
}

fun start() {
    // Call to start the game, probably from onResume or when the user clicks "Go" or something 
    updateTarget("x")
}

// Call these when the specific buttons are clicked
fun onClickX() {
    onClick("x", "y")
}

fun onClickY() {
    onClick("y", "z")
}

fun onClickZ() {
    onClick("z", "w")
}

fun onClickW() {
    onClick("w", "")
}
```

Comment: Let me give this a try i will be back with feedback